# PHP Open an existing csv/text file in header page

Tags: php, excel, header, save

Can i open an existing text file or csv file in the header of page? (i.e. when i set the header parameters below into php page :

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$document);
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

the file will be opened in mode alert (open/save) directly.But if i have the file with it's name (test.xls), how i can set the header parameters to open it in the header page???

let's say : a file named : 'test.xls', i want to do output a php page to open/save this file

```
$file='/temp/test.xls';// file existed and created previously.

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$file);
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

how proceed to do that?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? redirect and give out a file? Print a file before contents of a page? It's not clear, sorry.

Comment: Exactly, more details could help..

Comment: i want to open an existing file like a popup alert (open/save) like xls or text header, in general when we want to export data to excel or text file, we extract the data and prepare the header to excel or text for a file not created yet, but in this case the file has been created , i want to open it on header of page. See the question re-edited

Answer (score 0):

1. If the file is openly available, you can simply redirect to it:

   ```
   header('Location: /path/to/file.xls');
   ```
2. Otherwise, just send those headers you already have and just output the file:

   ```
   echo file_get_contents('file.xls');
   ```